# How do you grow a view upwards as content is added to it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I’m trying to programmatically append items to my view as the user interacts with my application. As in the picture when new items are added to the planner, they get appended to a view below the title and above a series of buttons.
Ideally all of the content will be nested in a ScrollView so as the title get pushed offscreen by content being appended to the list, the user can scroll up to that area. The idea is to allow the buttons and everything below appear to remain stationary as the list grows upwards pushing content offscreen in that direction. Preferably I’d like to do this in the most efficient way possible without a ListView or RecyclerView as the list will likely remain small; it would be great if the containing area for the items were a LinearLayout for example.

[scrollView layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yunvs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In a linear layout, use layout.addView(view, 0).  This will put it as the first child of the layout, which (assuming the layout is vertical) goes to the top.